# order by Item must appear in the select list if distinct is used

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to return a temp table in SQL joining another temp table using DISTINCT and ORDER BY clause.

I have a declared a table which returns a few things.

```
Declare @GrpItems TABLE (ID INT,
                         Name NVARCHAR(32),
                         Date DATETIME,
                         City NVARCHAR(32),
                         CityCode NVARCHAR(8),
                         CurrencySort NVARCHAR(16)   
                        )

INSERT INTO @GrpItems 
    SELECT  
        ID, Name, Date ,
        CityCodeorCaption   --this can be two type based on User input  CityCode or CityCaption 
    FROM
        RepeatItemTable
```

Now I have a different table where I want to insert and the procedure returns that table as the final result.

```
DECLARE @CurrencyTable TABLE (RowNumber INT Identity (1,1),
                              FK_Currency INT,
                              Value INT,
                              CityCode NVARCHAR(16),
                              CityCaption NVARCHAR(16)
                             )

INSERT INTO @Currency 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        gb.FK_Currency, cv.Value,
        c.CityCode, c.CityCaption
    FROM 
        Balance b
    JOIN 
        Currency c ON c.PK_Currency = b.FK_Currency
    JOIN 
        @GrpItems gi ON c.FK_Grpitem = gi.PK_Grpitem
    ORDER BY 
        gi.CityCodeorName
```

I know somewhere I need group by but I am not sure or a select clause in where filter

I think

```
ORDER BY 
   gi.CityCodeOrNAME 
        WHEN 'City' THEN City 
        ELSE CityCode ASC 
        END
```

Which does not seem to work? I need the Distinct because it might break some other logic.

```
Select * from @CurrencyTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `group by` instead of `select distinct`.  That will solve your problem:

```
SELECT gb.FK_Currency, cv.Value, c.CityCode, c.CityCaption
FROM Balance b JOIN
     Currency c
     ON c.PK_Currency = b.FK_Currency JOIN
     @GrpItems gi
     ON c.FK_Grpitem = gi.PK_Grpitem
GROUP BY gb.FK_Currency, cv.Value, c.CityCode, c.CityCaption
ORDER BY MAX(gi.CityCodeorName) ;
```

Note the use of the aggregation function in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CityCodeOrNAME = 'City' 
              THEN City
              ELSE CityCode 
         END
```

In case you need differnt orders you can also separate them

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CityCodeOrNAME = 'City' THEN City END DESC,
         CASE WHEN CityCodeOrNAME <> 'City' THEN CityCode END ASC
```